# MarkLogic clustering, after the fact

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-9

Is there any way to add two MarkLogic nodes into a cluster after they have already been initialized? I have automated scripts to build out new nodes in AWS using the ML amis. With that configuration, the nodes are already configured when they are started up and don't have that initialization screen for joining a cluster. Is there any way to join nodes that are already in this state?

Comment: As suggested by Kristina Morales Martin, I am going to follow the steps described here (http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/admin-api/cluster#id_52842) to join the nodes after they have already initialized.

Answer (score 0):

I had to modify the script at http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/admin-api/cluster#id_52842 for it to work for me.

The main changes were:

- As the servers are already initialized, (1) does not need to be done. I just switched it to fetch the timestamp.
- Use $AUTH_CURL instead of $CURL for the endpoints, because they are now all secured.

-

```
#!/bin/bash
################################################################
# Use this script to initialize and add one or more hosts to a
# MarkLogic Server cluster. The first (bootstrap) host for the
# cluster should already be fully initialized.  
#
# Use the options to control admin username and password,
# authentication mode, and the security realm. At least two hostnames
# must be given: A host already in the cluster, and at least one host
# to be added to the cluster. Only minimal error checking is performed,
# so this script is not suitable for production use.
#
# Usage:  this_command [options] cluster-host joining-host(s)
#
################################################################

USER="admin"
PASS="password"
AUTH_MODE="anyauth"
N_RETRY=5
RETRY_INTERVAL=10

#######################################################
# restart_check(hostname, baseline_timestamp, caller_lineno)
#
# Use the timestamp service to detect a server restart, given a
# a baseline timestamp. Use N_RETRY and RETRY_INTERVAL to tune
# the test length. Include authentication in the curl command
# so the function works whether or not security is initialized.
#   $1 :  The hostname to test against
#   $2 :  The baseline timestamp
#   $3 :  Invokers LINENO, for improved error reporting
# Returns 0 if restart is detected, exits with an error if not.
#
function restart_check {
  LAST_START=`$AUTH_CURL "http://$1:8001/admin/v1/timestamp"`
  for i in `seq 1 ${N_RETRY}`; do
    if [ "$2" == "$LAST_START" ] || [ "$LAST_START" == "" ]; then
      sleep ${RETRY_INTERVAL}
      LAST_START=`$AUTH_CURL "http://$1:8001/admin/v1/timestamp"`
    else
      return 0
    fi
  done
  echo "ERROR: Line $3: Failed to restart $1"
  exit 1
}


#######################################################
# Parse the command line

OPTIND=1
while getopts ":a:p:u:" opt; do
  case "$opt" in
    a) AUTH_MODE=$OPTARG ;;
    p) PASS=$OPTARG ;;
    u) USER=$OPTARG ;;
    \?) echo "Unrecognized option: -$OPTARG" >&2; exit 1 ;;
  esac
done
shift $((OPTIND-1))

if [ $# -ge 2 ]; then
  BOOTSTRAP_HOST=$1
  shift
else
  echo "ERROR: At least two hostnames are required." >&2
  exit 1
fi
ADDITIONAL_HOSTS=$@

# Curl command for all requests. Suppress progress meter (-s),
# but still show errors (-S)
CURL="curl -s -S"
# Curl command when authentication is required, after security
# is initialized.
AUTH_CURL="${CURL} --${AUTH_MODE} --user ${USER}:${PASS}"


#######################################################
# Add one or more hosts to a cluster. For each host joining
# the cluster:
#   (1) POST /admin/v1/init (joining host)
#   (2) GET /admin/v1/server-config (joining host)
#   (3) POST /admin/v1/cluster-config (bootstrap host)
#   (4) POST /admin/v1/cluster-config (joining host)
# GET /admin/v1/timestamp is used to confirm restarts.

for JOINING_HOST in $ADDITIONAL_HOSTS; do
  echo "Adding host to cluster: $JOINING_HOST..."

  # (1) Initialize MarkLogic Server on the joining host
  TIMESTAMP=`$AUTH_CURL -X GET \
     http://${JOINING_HOST}:8001/admin/v1/timestamp`
  if [ "$TIMESTAMP" == "" ]; then
    echo "ERROR: Failed to initialize $JOINING_HOST" >&2
    exit 1
  fi
  #restart_check $JOINING_HOST $TIMESTAMP $LINENO

  # (2) Retrieve the joining host's configuration
JOINER_CONFIG=`$AUTH_CURL -X GET -H "Accept: application/xml" \
        http://${JOINING_HOST}:8001/admin/v1/server-config`
  echo $JOINER_CONFIG | grep -q "^<host"
  if [ "$?" -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "ERROR: Failed to fetch server config for $JOINING_HOST"
    exit 1
  fi

  # (3) Send the joining host's config to the bootstrap host, receive
  #     the cluster config data needed to complete the join. Save the
  #     response data to cluster-config.zip.
  $AUTH_CURL -X POST -o cluster-config.zip -d "group=Default" \
        --data-urlencode "server-config=${JOINER_CONFIG}" \
        -H "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" \
        http://${BOOTSTRAP_HOST}:8001/admin/v1/cluster-config
  if [ "$?" -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "ERROR: Failed to fetch cluster config from $BOOTSTRAP_HOST"
    exit 1
  fi
  if [ `file cluster-config.zip | grep -cvi "zip archive data"` -eq 1 ]; then
    echo "ERROR: Failed to fetch cluster config from $BOOTSTRAP_HOST"
    exit 1
  fi

  # (4) Send the cluster config data to the joining host, completing
  #     the join sequence.
  TIMESTAMP=`$AUTH_CURL -X POST -H "Content-type: application/zip" \
      --data-binary @./cluster-config.zip \
      http://${JOINING_HOST}:8001/admin/v1/cluster-config \
      | grep "last-startup" \
      | sed 's%^.*<last-startup.*>\(.*\)</last-startup>.*$%\1%'`
  restart_check $JOINING_HOST $TIMESTAMP $LINENO
  rm ./cluster-config.zip

  echo "...$JOINING_HOST successfully added to the cluster."
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that if you utilize the Managed Cluster feature of MarkLogic you do not need any deployment or cluster joining scripts of your own, the feature manages it transparently for you in addition to providing HA via automatic replacement of failed nodes, re-attaching to EBS storage and the ability to pause and restart the cluster at any time.  Using the Managed Cluster feature, a cluster of any size (>=3) can surive total failure of *all nodes* and recover automatically without manual intervention.  Adding nodes is a matter of changing a parameter in the cloud formation script. You may want to look into this feature for your next cluster.

Comment: Thanks DALDEI. We do follow that where we actually build a cluster ahead of time, though we have modified the cloud formation to be in Ansible. This case was more for when we start our with a single mode already and we need to make it a cluster because the processing is burdening the Dev server.